# Spring MVC or Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

For a large company (web) project, do you recommend using Spring MVC or Spring-Boot?

Spring-Boot, in terms of configuration, is very easy compared to Spring MVC.

I wonder if I use Spring-Boot can have the same advantages of Spring MVC?

What do you recommend?

Comment: The choice is not *between* MVC and Boot because Boot [can use MVC (and autoconfigure it)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc). If you mean "Boot or Boot-less?" then it depends on how open to innovation (and associated risks) your company is. Either way, [asking for recommendation *is* off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realized that spring boot can be configured to spring mvc. But I am confused whether to use Spring-Boot or Spring MVC both have the same characteristics (Spring boot easy to set up). From your experience as you use?

Comment: Spring boot save your time to configure an application have default beans and manage the dependencies too. But, spring-boot and spring-mvc have different goals. If you want to use spring-boot with spring-mvc you can and you don't need to setup anything unless you want to override custom configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For my future project will use Spring -Boot . I think Spring -Boot is easier to configure and save a lot of time .

Comment: And spring boot is not incompatible with a war packaging and a external servlet container, see [58.2 Packaging executable jar and war files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will certainly use Spring -Boot for a web project . Spring -Boot eliminates all code xml . I hope that in future we will use this form to all projects and eliminate .xml configurations that are very annoying and incomprehensible for large web projects .

Comment: so finally, you run the fat jar or create war file :). I did  simple wrk test, then deploy war file on wildfly run 20% faster than spring fat jar

Comment: Spring MVC doesn't require XML configuration, but some dependencies might. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Comment: The question might be to use Spring Boot or not into a Spring project, which I would definitelly answer as a 'yes' for a new project. But Boot and MVC are themselves fully compatible. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922914/difference-between-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot/32923000#32923000) explain their differences.

Comment: Have to check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232727/9437031

Answer (score 108, accepted):

My personal advice is to definitely use Spring Boot for many reasons.

1. The first is that Boot is the "future of Spring". That means that with Boot 
   you can benefit from many commitments of the Spring community. Most of the 
   Spring projects today are completely
   integrated with Boot, even the community starts to develop many
   applications based on Boot. For example for managing and monitoring.
   I can suggest to see [Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin)
2. With Spring Boot you can benefit from very nice and useful features such as
   actuator and remote shell for managing and monitoring, that
   improves your application with production ready features that are very
   useful.
3. Very nice and powerful properties and configuration controls - you
   can configure your application with `application.properties/yml`
   and extend the boot in a very simple and impressive way, even the
   management in terms of overriding is very powerful.
4. It is one of the first micro-service ready platforms, and in my opinion
   nowadays it is the best! Even if you don't build a micro-service
   project with boot you can benefit of using a modern approach in which
   you have a auto-consistent jar that can benefit from all the features
   that I described above or if you prefer you can impose the packaging
   as a classical war and deploy your war in any of the containers that 
   you want.
5. Use of an intelligent and convention over configuration approach that
   reduces the startup and configuration phase of your
   project significantly. In fact you have a set of starter Maven or Gradle dependencies
   that simplify the dependency management. Then with the
   auto-configuration characteristic you can benefit from a lot of
   standard configurations, that are introduced through the Conditional Configuration framework
   in Spring 4. You can override it with your specific
   configurations just defining your bean according with the
   convention that you can see in the auto-configure JAR of the Boot
   dependency. Remember that Spring is open-source and you can see the code. Also the documentation in my opinion is good.
6. Spring initializer is a cool tool attainable at this link:
   https://start.spring.io/ is a very cool tool just to create your project in a very fast way.

I hope that this reflection can help you decide what is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a little confusion here. I want to use Spring 4 in my project as I wont have to use `persistence.xml` configuration file and many other features. Can I have spring 4's features in spring boot? If yes how to do that

Comment: I would tend to agree if you're planning on doing things pretty vanilla. The amount of times I've attempted to go to boot cause headache and me yelling at the screen because boot tries to be too smart about what dependencies I have and end up having to do more to turn things off than I would to turn things on using a bootless project. A couple things that end up nightmarish is trying to work with LDAP where a db cache is needed, or configuring more than one DataSource has boot trying to create JdbcTemplate and hibernate instances without me knowing, and even starting the h3 database by itself.

Comment: Property configuration is also something I haven't worked out how to control. In bootless projects I would create an AppConfig class that has overloaded support for reading properties in my apps properties file that I can use in JSP's and SpEL but can't figure out how to do the same with boot.

Comment: What is an auto-consistent JAR?

Comment: When I talk about auto consisten jar I refer to the capability of srping boot of pakage the your app in a jar that have all the necessary for your app. In fact if your app is a stand alone app you can put the init configuration in the CommandLineRunner run method when if your app is a web-app boot will pakage your application with a embedded servlet container in a sipmle configuration way through application.properties file,  thanks at the capability of redifine the application properties with env prop, jvm paramiter and so on

Comment: Is this answer still valid (six-month later) I am looking into this, and I still dont understand why would people still use Spring, when they have the awesome Spring Boot? I mean I like Spring Boot very much, the idea of intelligent software that configures itself is very much awesome to me but I am very confused! again **why would people still use Spring, when they have the awesome Spring Boot?**

Comment: @AhmadHajjar, for a new project I would definitelly go with Spring Boot. Currently it's a completely mature tool. But keep in mind people need still to maintain plain Spring projects, some of them might be straight forward to move to Boot and others probably are so big that would make the migration process a pain.

Comment: Spring boot provides autoconfiguration. But this is helpful in very few cases. As in example, many large scale application does not use the default configuration, eg; to configure MongoDB. We need our explicit configuration. Also any Spring MVC can be initialized with start-up.jar. I think both Spring MVC and Spring Boot are similar. But definatly Spring Boot is build on top of Spring MVC.

Answer (score 41):

Spring Boot uses Spring MVC! It's just autoconfigured and ready to use when you import the spring-boot-starter-web jar. So you'd basically are talking about whether to use Spring Boot or manually setup your Spring Application...

Comment: Yep _+1, Spring boot is just autoconfiguration tool, Spring mvc is web framework

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone I understand that Spring MVC is a framework. You say Spring Boot is just a autoconfig tool, can it also be considered as a Framework?

Comment: @Jesse, well both of them can be considered as either tools or frameworks. But what people empashize here is that spring boot is rather a tool for the Spring mvc web framework. It will provide a  ready-configuration needed for the Spring mvc, though, the booty itself is in a form of framework. Finally, my english is so bad that it may already burn your face. Hehe

Comment: I agree to this and I will definetly use spring boot to do better with less work

Answer (score 24):

You can definitely go for Spring Boot. We have already started using Spring Boot for building enterprise application. It has lot of advantages, listing few below here:

1. Your project configuration will be pretty simple. No need to maintain XML file, all you need to know is how efficiently you can use [*application.properties*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) file.
2. Gives lot of default implementation, for instance if you need to send an email, it provides default implementation of `JavaMailSender`
3. Spring Hibernate and JPA integration will be pretty simple.

Like this there are many, you can explore based on your needs.

Comment: Spring boot is always preferred because you don't have to deal with verbose XML and they leverage micro-services architectures

Answer (score 10):

You can use Spring MVC with spring boot as @kryger said, they are non exclusive between them, and the configuration will be easier, also I recommend you to use http://www.thymeleaf.org/ which is template framework. Working with that is like working with JSP but thymeleaf integrates seamlessly with HTML, so your code will look very clean and you can add a lot of useful features.

Answer (score 9):

I think Spring Boot is more useful than the MVC, as it has many advantages and inbuilt features which make it more reliable than MVC. In Spring Boot most of the things are auto configured and there is no need of writing those xml as we do in the MVC, which can save time.

Spring Boot bundles a war file with server run-time like Tomcat. This allows easy distribution and deployment of web applications. As the industry is moving towards container based deployments, Spring Boot is useful in this context as well.

Spring MVC is web application framework. While you can do everything in Spring without Spring Boot, but Spring Boot helps you get things done faster.

Spring boot simplifies your Spring dependencies, no more version collisions,
can be run straight from a command line without an application container,
build more with less code - no need for XML, not even web.xml, auto-configuration, useful tools for running in production, database initialization,  environment specific config files, collecting metrics.

Basics of Spring Boot can be found [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very helpful for understanding about spring boot. One thing I am confused about is, if I will have to change the spring version that I am using, how would I do that with spring boot? I cannot see anywhere where  spring version is defined.

Comment: Did not use maven in your project? @viper

Comment: yes i have used maven. but using spring boot, i cannot see the spring dependencies there.