# Implementation of Spring Boot microservice using Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud

I am a beginner in Spring mvc, Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. I am trying to create Microservices using Spring Boot. I created a sample database CRUD operation as microservice in Spring Boot. Now I have A requirement that develop a microservice using Spring Cloud.

When I referring documentation seeing Spring tools for creating application in distributed environment. I am confused about why we are using Spring Cloud? And what is actually meant by Spring Cloud? Is there any relation with Spring mvc?

Comment: I think you should go through this great article https://dzone.com/articles/microservice-architecture-with-spring-cloud-and-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud is for developing some of the common patterns in distributed systems.

> Spring Cloud provides tools for developers to quickly build some of the common patterns in distributed systems (e.g. configuration management, service discovery, circuit breakers, intelligent routing, micro-proxy, control bus, one-time tokens, global locks, leadership election, distributed sessions, cluster state)
>   [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/)

For Spring Boot and Spring MVC, see this nice answer [difference-between-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32923000/5810894)

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I already seen those link.But my confusion is that the concepts of  configuration management, service discovery, circuit breakers, intelligent routing, micro-proxy, control bus, one-time tokens, global locks, leadership election, distributed sessions, cluster state. What is the importance of these when I creating a web services?? Can you help me to clarify those all things???

Comment: Ah, ok. Now i got it. To bring a bit of light into your confusion, best read this article https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices/
It is not covering spring boot or spring cloud, but will bring you an understanding on micro services with many of the same pattern that spring cloud is using (e.g. Service Discovery). Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok.Thank you..Will explore it.