# How to build a JSF application in Intellij using Maven

Tags: maven, jsf, intellij-idea

I'm having issues building a jsf web project using maven in Intellij, i go to `new project` -> `maven` and i can choose `create from archetype`, here i can find 3 different archetypes with jsf

- org.apache.maven.archerypes:softeu-archetype-jsf
- org.appfuse.archetypes:appfuse-basic-jsf
- org.appfuse.archertpes:appfuse-modular-jsf

With the first one `softeu-archetype-jsf` i have the following error when i try to import the dependencies **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:softeu-archetype-jsf:RELEASE)**.

When i try the other two, dependencies get downloaded properly but i am told i have no AspectJ, **IDEA was unable to resolve aspect library 'org.springframework:spring-aspects'** , i googled around and it's a [java extension developed from eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) . Honestly i don't want to have to set this up just to create a jsf web project. The only other option i found was to use this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965-maven-archetype-catalogs) to add more archetypes through url, but it has some issues since the page i have to go to has an infinite loading and doesn't work.

Is there some other solution for this ?

Comment: Why not create a simple web project or a Spring Boot project using Spring initializr and add JSF later on?

Comment: Because i wanna build the project using maven, jsf and spring are different mvc frameworks.

Comment: `Spring MVC` is a MVC framework. You can still build a Spring powered project with JSF as MVC framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922914/difference-between-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot

Comment: http://www.javaserverfaces.org/get-started I mean, no matter what, you're going to have to do some fiddling to get the initial setup correct. Then you can create your own archetype to make subsequent projects easier.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i started following it but many things are out of date, the `create` command doesn't exists and it got substituted by `generate`, also all the _next steps_ and documentation links don't work.