# Spring Boot vs Spring MVC (In depth)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've got the basic idea of, what both of them are and when they can be used. I've already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479814/spring-mvc-or-spring-boot) question as well. As of now what I understood was:

**Spring Boot** bundles a war file with server runtime like Tomcat. This allows easy distribution and deployment of web applications. As the industry is moving towards container based deployments, Spring Boot is useful in this context.

**Spring MVC** is a traditional web application framework that helps you to build web applications.

What I wanted to know is that, what can be the best practice when it comes to web applications and the differences of using either one of them in depth. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spring boot relies on Spring MVC. When you use Spring boot to develop web apps, you're using Spring MVC.

Comment: Spring boot makes development easier and you only need to worry about the business logic. Also as Spring boot application starts with main class. It can be deployed on cloud. for Sping MVC you need to use openshift.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that Spring MVC is a framework. Is Spring boot also a framework?